# Contact Bitmask

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

Heyo! I am trying to make my game restart when a ball touched a wall (aka a "danger"). I set up contact bit mask and PhysicsCategories but It just wont work. Can anyone help? It won't print "contact" when the ball touches the danger and I can't seem to find out why.

Also, how can I add another Physics Category for a "goal"? How do I add another UInt32 number? Can I just change the 0x1 to 0x2? or is there a certain why that I NEED to do. I'm new to this whole physics category thing, so its really confusing. I can't find a tutorial for what I am looking for specifically.

```
import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit



class GameScene: SKScene {

    var ball = SKSpriteNode()
    var danger1 = SKSpriteNode()
    var danger2 = SKSpriteNode()
    var goal = SKSpriteNode()


    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

        ball = self.childNode(withName: "ball") as! SKSpriteNode
        danger1 = self.childNode(withName: "danger1") as! SKSpriteNode
        danger2 = self.childNode(withName: "danger2") as! SKSpriteNode
        goal = self.childNode(withName: "goal") as! SKSpriteNode

        let border = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFrom: self.frame)
        border.friction = 0
        border.restitution = 0

        print("x: \(ball.position.x), y: \(ball.position.y)")

        danger1.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: danger1.size.width/2)
        danger1.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategories.dangerCategory
        danger2.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: danger2.size.width/2)
        danger2.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategories.dangerCategory

        ball.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: ball.size.width/2)
        ball.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategories.ballCategory
        ball.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategories.dangerCategory
        ball.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategories.none

        danger1.physicsBody?.isDynamic = true
        ball.physicsBody?.isDynamic = true
        goal.physicsBody?.isDynamic = true
        danger2.physicsBody?.isDynamic = true
        danger2.physicsBody!.affectedByGravity = false
        danger1.physicsBody!.affectedByGravity = false
        goal.physicsBody!.affectedByGravity = false
        ball.physicsBody!.affectedByGravity = false
        setupPhysics()

    }
    func setupPhysics() {
        physicsWorld.gravity = CGVector(dx: 0.0, dy: 0.0)
        physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        for touch in touches {
        }
    }

    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        for touch in touches {
            let location = touch.location(in: self)
            ball.position.x = location.x
            ball.position.y = location.y
        }
    }

    override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
        // Called before each frame is rendered
    }
}

extension GameScene: SKPhysicsContactDelegate {



    func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
        let contactMask = contact.bodyA.contactTestBitMask | contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask

        if contactMask == PhysicsCategories.ballCategory | PhysicsCategories.dangerCategory {
            print("Contact")
        }
    }

}
```

Settings.swift:

```
import SpriteKit

enum PhysicsCategories {
    static let none: UInt32 = 0
    static let ballCategory: UInt32 = 0x1           // 01
    static let dangerCategory: UInt32 = 0x1 << 1    // 10
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You set all of your bitmasks correctly so leave those the way they were. The problematic line is

```
let contactMask = contact.bodyA.contactTestBitMask | contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask
```

You are using bitwise arithmetic which means you're adding those bits (UInt32) together. Check out ([Bitwise Operators](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/AdvancedOperators.html))

What you want to do is compare two categoryBitmasks, not a contactBitMask and CategoryBitmask So just change the line above to this

```
let contactMask = contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask | contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask
```

Also to make more categories, just keep shifting the bits over

```
let Category4:UInt32 = 0x1 << 2
let Category5:UInt32 = 0x1 << 3
```

Etc.

Comment: Thank you! I am trying it now :)